# How to get the last Value from SimpleXMLElement Object?

Tags: php, xml

I tried a lot, but I can't figure it out. I have this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [BrowseNodeId] => 10829411 
    [Name] => Römertöpfe 
    [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
            ( 
                [BrowseNode] => 
                    SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( 
                    [BrowseNodeId] => 3311941 
                    [Name] => Töpfe & Pfannen 
                    [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                        ( 
                            [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                            ( 
                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3094896031 
                                [Name] => Kochen 
                                [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                                ( 
                                    [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 3169011 
                                        [Name] => Kategorien 
                                        [IsCategoryRoot] => 1 
                                        [Ancestors] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                                        ( 
                                            [BrowseNode] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                                                ( 
                                                [BrowseNodeId] => 3167641 
                                                [Name] => Küche, Haushalt & Wohnen 
        ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

I need the last value of it (the bold one):

> [Name] => **Küche, Haushalt & Wohnen**

But i don't know, how i can read out the last value. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Share your XML instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getting the last value with key as `Name` is your concern you can do it this way.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/809453) `tried with example XML`

```
$result="";
$array=json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($YOUR_XML_STRING)),true);
array_walk_recursive($array, function($value,$key) use (&$result){
    if($key=="Name")
    {
        $result=$value;
    }
});
print_r($result);
```